# App Crashing instantly, unexplained

Tags: android, eclipse

My code is written to first bring up a button in the LoginActivity and then when pressed load another activity.  But as of right now, the app crashes both on my S4 and an emulator on launch.  I have tried debugging mode but haven't received any useful information.  Here is my LoginActivity code (main activity):

```
package com.JTInc.tag;



import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;


public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public void gotomap (View View){
        Intent ii = new Intent(getActivity(), MapActivity.class);
        startActivity(ii);
    }

    private void startActivity(Intent ii) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private Context getActivity() {
         //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is the mapviewer.xml code (the main layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gotomap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/gotomap"
            android:onClick="gotomap" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Any and all help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Please post the exception data from your logcat output.

Comment: remove startActivity method. I think it is part of FragmentActivity that may cause problem.

Comment: `getActivity()` returns `null`?

Comment: What should the getActivity() be?  I replaced the "this," in the intent line with the "getActivity()" because this kept having errors.

Comment: The explanation is in your logcat.

Comment: Unless any one else is interested, I am taking a largely different approach to my project now and this can be deleted.

Comment: Remove getactivity () and startActivity() simply write  gotomap (startActivity(new Intent (classname.this, nextclass.class));